# VSCode on Mac arm64 doesn't seem to recognize symlinks in includePath

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, symlink, include-path

I am trying to compile/debug a C program with VSCode that I intend to port from Linux to MacOS (Mac Studio). The program uses the arb arbitrary precision library that I installed with homebrew. My program uses 2 include files

```
#include "acb.h"
#include "flint/profiler.h"
```

that reside in the `/opt/homebrew/include` directory. When I first debug the file, I get an error message indicating that these include files were not found. I do the "quick fix" and edit the includePath in the c_cpp_properties.json file adding a line to includePath.

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/include/**"
            ],
```

However, I still get the error message 'acb.h' file not found.

All include files in `/opt/homebrew/include` are symlinks to different locations in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` but I thought that shouldn't matter, I have no problems whatsoever compiling the program on the command line using `-I/opt/homebrew/include`. I also tried `"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/**"` in the includePath to no avail. I fact, the only way I could get VSCode find my include files was to give their absolute path but even then VSCode couldn't find any include files that were referenced inside acb.h or flint/profiler.h.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify: Are you aware that an IDE like VSC and a compiler are different beasts? Which of both emits that error message? I assume that it's the IDE, because your command line compiling works. But please make it explicit.

Comment: I don't think `**` recursively searches through symbolic links. I wouldn't recommend using `**` at all in this context (you are likely to stumble upon duplicate names and you don't want that). Do use a full path to every separate include directory. If VSC complains that it cannot find `foo/bar/qux.h`, you need to add the *parent directory of `foo`* to the list.

Comment: my question is why you're getting an error about include files not being found while _debugging_... where exactly is that error shown? a screenshot might actually help here just to see where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding all my command line arguments to the args list in tasks.json solved the problem.